# Doob–Meyer decomposition

Tags: stochastic-processes

Let $X_n = \sum_{m≤n} 1_{B_m} $and suppose $B_n \in F_n$. What is the Doob
decomposition for $X_n$ ? I can write it down from the construction of the theorem, but is there any neat way showing the result?

Comment: What does $1_{B_m}$ mean? It looks like an indicator on some event related to $B_m$, but what is the event exactly?

Comment: @AlexR. $B_m$ is an event (more precisely, $B_m \in F_m$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It follows from the fact that $1_{B_k}$ is $\mathcal{F}_{n-1}$-measurable for $k \leq n-1$ that

$$\mathbb{E}(X_n \mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1}) = X_{n-1} + \mathbb{P}(B_n \mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1}).$$

Subtracting $A_n := \sum_{k=1}^n \mathbb{P}(B_k \mid \mathcal{F}_{k-1})$ on both sides yields

$$\mathbb{E}(X_n - A_n \mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1}) = X_{n-1} - A_{n-1}.$$

This shows that $M_n := X_n-A_n$ is a martingale. Consequently, the Doob decomposition is given by

$$X_n = \underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^n 1_{B_k}-\mathbb{P}(B_k \mid \mathcal{F}_{k-1})}_{\text{martingale}}+ \underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^n \mathbb{P}(B_k \mid \mathcal{F}_{k-1})}_{\text{predictable}}.$$

Comment: Hi, saz. I found your and Alex's answer is different. I think you are both right. Does that mean it is possible to have two answers?

Comment: @Tuyet No, the Doob decomposition is unique (at least, if we require $M_0 = A_0=0$).

Comment: Hi,saz. Can I decompose it like $$X_n = \underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^n 1_{B_k}-\mathbb{P}(B_k \mid \mathcal{F}_{k-1})+\mathbb{P}(B_1 \mid \mathcal{F}_{0})}_{\text{martingale}}+ \underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^n \mathbb{P}(B_k \mid \mathcal{F}_{k-1})-\mathbb{P}(B_1 \mid \mathcal{F}_{0})}_{\text{predictable}}.$$ To make the predicable part start from $0$? Thanks!

Comment: Because I see $X_0$ is not defined here. So I make it start from $A_1=0$? Is that right?:)

Comment: @Tuyet yes, you can do so.